# Multivariate method of moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In *Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas and Selected Topics (Kjell A. Doksum, Peter J. Bickel)*, problem 2.1.17 defined "multivariate method of moments" like this:

[image: screenshot]

Then in problem 2.2.29(b), it asks the following:

[image: screenshot]

Now I don't see how that would be true. I can only imagine two scenarios:

1. We should take $X = (Y_1,...,Y_n)$ and one sample. But then there is no choice $j,k,r,s$ such that $\hat{m}_{j k r s} = \bar{Y}$.
2. We should take $X_1 = (Y_1), ..., X_n = (Y_n)$. But then we have two problems: First, the $X_1,...,X_n$ are not i.i.d., so it wouldn't match the definition. And second, why would we be referred to the "multivariate" method of moments, when it's actually just a usual 1-dimensional method of moments.

Do you agree?